# How To create update API in yii?

Tags: yii2

I created an api named valid which is not working. Postman says

```
    "name": "Not Found",
    "message": "Page not found.",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 404,
    "type": "yii\\web\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "previous": {
        "name": "Invalid Route",
        "message": "Unable to resolve the request \"user/valid/1\".",
        "code": 0,
        "type": "yii\\base\\InvalidRouteException"
    }
}
```

My controller name is user controller.
Here is my function

```
public function actionValid($id)
{
    return 'example';
}
```

i called my route as `/user/valid/1`.
Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Show you complete controller code, and make sure you defined the route jn urlManager

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-routing see the `extraPatterns` url rules for rest api

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved this.
If you want to create your own apis in yii, You must follow these steps.
First add your route in `UrlManager` Like this

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
            'controller' => 'user',
            'extraPatterns' => [
               'POST valid/<id>' => 'valid',
               'GET listing' => 'listing
            ]
        ],
    ],
]
```

Now, call your route like this `users/valid/{your-id}` and `users/listing`. Make sure to use a plural of your controller's name.

For example, a request of POST `/users/data` would mean accessing the `actiondata` function in your usercontroller.